# .net Computer sleep and Disposed is not called

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, dispose

In my application I start a worker thread from a custom user control. When the control is disposed I abort the thread. The problem is that when the computer goes to sleep and the user closes the application my control is not disposed any more.

If I start a thread in my application how can I force it to be stopped when application is closed?

Comment: Do you still have a reference to the thread when the computer wakes up?  Also - what do you mean the control isn't disposed any more?  Do you get an exception when you try to call Dispose?

Comment: Is the thread a background thread?

Comment: Does the app wake up again or is it killed in its sleep?

Comment: How can the user close the application if the computer is sleeping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When the control is disposed I abort the thread.

Bad idea. Aborting threads can (and often does) corrupt memory like data structures and such.

> If I start a thread in my application how can I force it to be stopped
>   when application is closed?

You need to set the `Thread.IsBackground = true`.